# Angular auto trigger specific directive in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an interesting situation.
I have a directive with isolate scope that generate list of numbers and the user can choose numbers like in lottery. 
The problem i have is that i required minimum of 1 line, if the user pick only one line so when he click play i want to auto trigger the next directive in the ng-repeat to pick for him numbers, I made this plunker so you guys can understand better and help me.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vWGmSEpinf7wxRUnqyWq?p=preview

```
 <div ng-repeat="line in [0,1,2,3]">
    <div line line-config="lineConfig">

    </div>
  </div>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.lineConfig = {
    guessRange: 10
  }

  $scope.lines = [];

  $scope.$on('lineAdded', function(event, line) {
    $scope.lines.push(line);
  });


  $scope.play = function() {

    /// here i want to check if $scope.lines.length 
    //is less then one if yes then auto trigger the next 
    //line directive  to auto do quick pick and continue


  }

})
  .directive('line', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'line.html',
      scope: {
        lineConfig: '='
      },
      link: function($scope, elem, attr) {

        var guessRange = $scope.lineConfig.guessRange;

        $scope.cells = [];

        $scope.line = {
          nums: []
        };

        $scope.$watch('line', function(lotLine) {
          var finaLine = {
            line: $scope.line
          }
          if ($scope.line.nums.length > 4) {
            $scope.$emit('lineAdded', finaLine);
          }

        }, true);

        _(_.range(1, guessRange + 1)).forEach(function(num) {
          $scope.cells.push({
            num: num,
            isSelected: false
          });
        });

        $scope.userPickNum = function(cell) {
          if (cell.isSelected) {
            cell.isSelected = false;
            _.pull($scope.lotLine.nums, cell.num);
          } else {
            cell.isSelected = true;
            $scope.lotLine.nums.push(cell.num);
          }
        };

        $scope.quickPick = function() {
          $scope.clearLot();
          $scope.line.nums = _.sample(_.range(1, guessRange + 1), 5);
          _($scope.line.nums).forEach(function(num) {
            num = _.find($scope.cells, {
              num: num
            });
            num.isSelected = true;
          });
        }

        $scope.clearLot = function() {
          _($scope.cells).forEach(function(num) {
            num.isSelected = false;
          });
          $scope.line.nums = [];
        }
      }
    }

  })
```

Comment: what do you mean by _next_ directive?

Comment: The next line directive, I want the quickPick on his scope to be trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the $index (exists automatically in the ng-repeat scope) - variable into the directive and cause it to broadcast an event unique for ($index + 1) which is the $index for the next instance.

The event could be broadcasted from the $rootScope or a closer scope that's above the repeat.
Then you could capture the event in there.

Probably not the best way to do it.
I can try to elaborate if anything is unclear.

**EDIT**

So I played around alittle and came up with this: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/ChRCyF7yQcN580umVfX1?p=preview
Rather

Rather than using events or services I went with using a directive controller to act as the parent over all the line directives inside it:

```
.directive('lineHandler', function () {
    return {
        controller: function () {
            this.lines = [];
        }
    }
 })
```

Then requiring 'lineHandler' controller inside the 'line' directive - the controller being a singleton (same instance injected into all the line directives) - you can then setup that controller to handle communication between your directives.

I commented most of my code in the updated plnkr and setup an example of what I think you requested when clicking in one list - affecting the one beneath.

I hope this helps and if anything is unclear I will try to elaborate.

Comment: I dont understand how, if you can fork my plunker this will be more helpful please.

Comment: I'll try it out later if nobody else gets ahead of me.

Comment: And try to think about situation that the user pick only the last line so i dont think your solution will work then.